# How to export csv from datagridview only visible column in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm working on scraping program, the next step from my program after scraping item is generate/export from datagridview into csv file. I have made the save code like below, but i just want to export only a visible column. How can i do like that?

```
Private Sub CmdCSV_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmdCSV.Click
        Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
        sfd.FileName = "export-csv"
        sfd.Filter = "CSV File | *.csv"

        If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(sfd.FileName)
                Dim dgvColumnNames As List(Of String) = DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).ToList().Select(Function(c) c.Name).ToList()

                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(";", dgvColumnNames))

                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    Dim rowData As New List(Of String)

                    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
                        rowData.Add(Convert.ToString(row.Cells(column.Name).Value))
                    Next
                    sw.WriteLine(String.Join(";", rowData))
                Next

            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there's no point calling `ToList` twice here:

```vb
Dim dgvColumnNames As List(Of String) = DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).ToList().Select(Function(c) c.Name).ToList()
```

You don't need a generic `List` to do the `Select`, so drop the first `ToList`:

```vb
Dim dgvColumnNames = DataGridView1.Columns.
                                   Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).
                                   Select(Function(c) c.Name).
                                   ToList()
```

If you want to filter that list to include only visible columns, that's what you do. The `Where` method is how you filter:

```vb
Dim dgvColumnNames = DataGridView1.Columns.
                                   Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).
                                   Where(Function(c) c.Visible).
                                   Select(Function(c) c.Name).
                                   ToList()
```

You should also replace this:

```vb
Dim rowData As New List(Of String)

For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
    rowData.Add(Convert.ToString(row.Cells(column.Name).Value))
Next
```

with this:

```vb
Dim rowData As New List(Of String)

For Each columnName In dgvColumnNames
    rowData.Add(Convert.ToString(row.Cells(columnName).Value))
Next
```

or, more simply, this:

```vb
Dim rowData = dgvColumnNames.Select(Function(s) row.Cells(columnName).Value.ToString()).ToList()
```

That last `ToList` isn't required either, because `String.Join` accepts an `IEnumerable(Of String)`. Don't take the extra time and effort to convert things to a generic `List` unless you actually need one.

Comment: aah i see, thank you. And i want to ask about header of column. I have header column (i.e Stock Supplier), but why in csv my header is getting from Design Name (STOCK_SUPPLIER) instead of HeaderText (Stock Supplier)? @John

Comment: @framadh, you need to learn how the `DataGridView` works. The name of a column and its header text are not the same thing. If you put the names into the file then the file will contain the names, not the header text.

Comment: yeaa, how if I want put the header text into the file instead of names? @John

Comment: @framadh, that has nothing to do with the topic of the question. You don't ask additional questions in the comments of an answer. If you have another question, post another question. That said, you might want to put some thought and effort into it for yourself first. I find it very hard to believe that you could find out how to get the header text for a grid column if you made the effort to search the web.